# Cannot pass parameter inside stored procedure in redshift

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have written the procedure which calls the parameter in the select query, but it's not working. When I print that parameter it's working fine, but with the select query, it's not working.

I have used Aginity workbench for redshift to execute the stored procedure.

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE get_tbl_name(IN tablename varchar, IN columnname VARCHAR, IN mindate varchar) AS $$
Declare
evalmindate varchar;
BEGIN
Raise info 'tablename = %, columnname = %, mindate = %', tablename,columnname,mindate;
if mindate is null then
select min(columnname) into evalmindate from tablename;
else
evalmindate=mindate;
end if;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Calling Proc:
call get_tbl_name('test_bq', 'date',NULL);

Output:
tablename = test_bq, columnname = date, mindate = <NULL>
Error Message
42601: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

From the output, we can able to see the parameter inside the procedure when I print, but I can't pass the parameter to the select query, it throwing an error. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: to start with `select min(columnname) into evalmindate from tablename;` is not correct, you are not using variables, literally you are trying to query `columnname` in a table called `tablename`

Comment: @mdem7 Even if I pass the parameter to the variable and passed the variable to select query it is not working. Getting same error.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the variable as a column or table name directly in a stored procedure query. Instead you need to compose a query string and execute that.

Also the `INTO var` syntax needs to come first in a plain query and *last* in an `EXECUTE`.

You have:

```
select min(columnname) into evalmindate from tablename;
```

Try this:

```
EXECUTE 'select min('|| columnname ||') from '|| tablename ||';' INTO evalmindate;
```